# C# deleting rows in DataTable

Tags: c#, ms-access, datatable

I delete rows in a DataTable with this code:

```
if (x == "y" || x == "yes")           
{             
    dt.Rows.RemoveAt(id);  
}
```

How I can save changes (delete row) in MS Access?
I have code like this, but this doest not work

```
OleDbCommand delCmd = new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM PERSONA WHERE ID=?",con1);
delCmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@ID",OleDbType.Integer, @ID));

foreach (DataRow dro in dt.GetChanges().Rows)           
{
   if (dro.RowState == DataRowState.Deleted)                                                   
   {    
      con1.Open();    
      delCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();    
      con1.Close();
   }    
}
```

Comment: RemoveAt removes row by index, not id

Answer (score 0):

You're not specifying the correct ID.  You need to add the parameter to the command within your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the rows using the Delete method. This will mark the rows to be deleted when using Update on a table adapter. You are just removing rows from the collection; not from the database.

Comment: ok, but when i delete rows with Delete method, then i can not view these rows, because C# gives me an errors, cannot not view deleted rows, smth like that, how to deal with it ? how to view deleted rows ?

Comment: Create a DataView and apply a fiter to see the rows that will be deleted. See halfway this article: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/netframeworkclasses/article.php/c6791